# Meta analysis with multilevel apporach

Tags: r

I want to do meta analysis with multilevel approach using proportions measured before and after administering interventions in communities. In metafor which measure is apt to use "PLO" or PFT"? I have 4 moderators too. Of the 17 studies that I have 4 studies have 2 communities each given different interventions ie different dosages of same drug. I used the following commands:

```
salt<- escalc(measure="PLO", xi=pos, ni=sur, data=salt,add=1/2, to="all")

model1<-rma(yi, vi, method="FE", data=salt) for fixed effects model (Traditional MA)
model2<-rma(yi, vi, data=salt) for Random effects vmodel (Traditional MA)
model3<-rma(yi, vi, mods=~factor(intcode)+factor(smrsz)+durint+basemf+percap, data=salt) for mixed effects model including moderators (Traditional MA)
model4<-rma.mv(yi, vi, random=~1|stdy, data=salt) - random effect multilevel model
model5<-rma(yi, vi, mods=~factor(intcode)+factor(smrsz)+durint+basemf+percap, random=~1|stdy, data=salt)
```

Here stdy gives the study id. Which command should i use?

Are these commands appropriate for the type of analysis I want to do?

Comment: Formatting should be improved

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use logit transformed proportions `(measure="PLO"`) or something like arcsine square-root transformed proportions (`measure="PAS"`) or Freeman-Tukey double arcsine transformed proportions (`measure="PFT"`) depends on various things, most importantly the size of the studies and whether the outcome of interest is very rare of very common (i.e., whether the underlying true proportions are expected to be close to 0 or 1). But in the end, it's probably a good idea to do a sensitivity analysis anyway, to check whether conclusions are unchanged regardless of which measure you use.

As for the models, models 1-3 are standard meta-analytic models and the syntax here is fine. In model 4, you are only adding random effects at the study level, but this assumes that all of the heterogeneity is due to differences between studies and that there is no heterogeneity within studies. This is usually not correct, so you should add random effects at the study and the outcome level. Something like this:

```
salt$id <- 1:nrow(salt)
rma.mv(yi, vi, random=~1|stdy/id, data=salt)
```

See also: http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011

In model 5, you have a typo -- you should be using `rma.mv()`, not `rma()`, when you use the `random` argument. And again, use `random=~1|stdy/id`.

Comment: Thank you, Wolfgang, for helping me out with the comments. Well, I also want to know if this is the approach, when the some of the studies have two interventions (a change in dosage of the same drug) tested in two different communities? Will model5 ie rma.mv with moderators may be appropriate ...as it considers study at level 2 and all communities at level 2? Suppose I want to include time ie studies carried out in 1980s, 1990s and in 2000 as a level, how do i incorporate the same in this model?